# Dynamic table data visible in query editor but blank in data view

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I've been struggling with a problem in PowerBI that at first glance should be easy and straightforward, but seems to be quite the contrary.

In short, I have some tables that I'm referencing dynamically, in order to expand their columns and do additional processing. When I'm building in the Query Editor, everything seems to be fine. The preview data in the editor is showing, and is correct. However, once I click Close and Apply, the data view in PowerBI does **not** show those referenced tables, but the cells seem to be **empty**.

Now, the details.
My tables are these:
[image: Tables Overview]

Table `shops` contains 3 records that we'll use to dynamically reference the actual tables `shop_thehouse`, `shop_goldforex` and `shop_goldline`.
[image: Table shops content]

Table `shops_all` is based on table `shops` and adds a column that dynamically references the other tables.

```
let
    Source = shops,
    AddedTables = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Data", each Expression.Evaluate("shop_" & Text.From([shop]), #sections[Section1]))
in
    AddedTables
```

Table `shops_all` shows like this in the editor, and contains the correct data, which means the dynamic referencing works fine.
[image: Table shops in the editor]

However, when clicking Close & Apply, we see this in the Data View. The Data column is empty.
If it were not empty, it would show `[Table]` in the cell.
[image: Table shops_all in Data View]

I then tried to add another column to `shops_all`, but this time with a static reference to one of the base tables.

```
let
    Source = shops,
    AddedTables = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Data", each Expression.Evaluate("shop_" & Text.From([shop]), #sections[Section1])),
    AddedFixedReference = Table.AddColumn(AddedTables, "FixedRef", each shop_thehouse)
in
    AddedFixedReference
```

Now each cell in the `FixedRef` column contains the data of `shop_thehouse`. So far so good.
[image: Added Fixed Reference]

After clicking Apply & Close, we now see this in the Data View
[image: Data View with Fixed Reference added]

As expected, column `FixedRef` shows `[Table]` in each cell.
But - and this was unexpected to me - we now also see that the record for shop `thehouse` also shows `[Table]` in the `Data` column, which contains the dynamic reference.

I tried adding another `FixedRef2` column that contains a fixed reference to another base table, and that shows an additional `[Table]` in the corresponding cell.

```
let
    Source = shops,
    AddedTables = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Data", each Expression.Evaluate("shop_" & Text.From([shop]), #sections[Section1])),
    AddedFixedReference = Table.AddColumn(AddedTables, "FixedRef", each shop_thehouse),
    AddedFixedReference2 = Table.AddColumn(AddedFixedReference, "FixedRef2", each shop_goldforex)
in
    AddedFixedReference2
```

[image: FixedRef2]

How is this possible?
I completely do not understand this.
How do I get the dynamic reference to show `[Table]` in the Data View, **without** having to add the `FixedRef` columns?

btw, table `shops_all` has `Enable load` checked, so that's probably not it.
[image: Enable Load on shops_all]

ps: I'm using the June 2022 version of PowerBI Desktop.
[image: PowerBI Desktop Version]

**[Edit 20 jun 2022]**
Because most reactions say that I should just expand the table, I'm going to post some screenshots proving that this is not the solution. As you can see, after expanding the table in the Query Editor, everything looks fine. The correct data is shown.

```
let
    Source = shops,
    AddedTables = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Data", each Expression.Evaluate("shop_" & Text.From([shop]), #sections[Section1])),
    ExpandedData = Table.ExpandTableColumn(AddedTables, "Data", {"description", "bid", "ask"}, {"description", "bid", "ask"})
in
    ExpandedData
```

[image: Expanded tables]

However, when I click Close and Apply, the Data View shows up blank (same after refresh):

[image: Data View with tables expanded]

This is the reason as to why I didn't show this in my original post.
It's because I know for a fact that the issue must be in the `AddedTables` step, which is yielding blank or null objects in the Data View.
This in contradiction to the Query Editor where the `AddedTables` step does not return blank/null and clearly show a `[Table]` object which contains the correct data.
For some reason unknown to me, it works in the Query Editor, but not in the Data View.

**[Edit 20 jun 2022 part 2]**

As requested, sharing the .pbix file through Google Drive
[StackOverflow_Question_72679896.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16vX7Yj8b9LIff7q1ktFd7E0PoHbWi65Q/view?usp=sharing)

You'll have to adjust the `Path` parameter to point to the correct directory, so the accompanying .xls can be found.
[image: Path parameter]

Comment: This is logical because your cell (Data) holds a complete table and when you click on it it shows the data (you did this for all 3 sets). However when you Click apply, you cannot expect that PBI magically shows you that data. You will need to expand the column "Data" to be able to return (and view) the data in PBI. So add the step and you should be ok.

Comment: I already did that extra step. Nothing shows. The data tables in the cells are really empty or null.

Comment: From your example I cannot see this. I can even read you are getting a table based on your example...  Did you click on the 2 arrows on your data column?

Comment: Yes, I did click the 2 arrows to expand the table, but since the data didn't show up in the Data View, I deleted that step again, because clearly the issue is caused by the cellls containing no Table object. I'll add screenshots of the table expand step tomorrow to show you.

Comment: Added section [Edit 20 jun 2022] to clarify that expanding the table in the Data column is not the problem.

Comment: Added [Edit 20 jun 2022 part 2] section with .pbix file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
let
    Source = shops,
    AddedTables = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Data", each Expression.Evaluate("shop_" & Text.From([shop]), [shop_thehouse =shop_thehouse, shop_goldforex=shop_goldforex, shop_goldline = shop_goldline ])),
    #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(AddedTables, "Data", {"description", "bid", "ask"}, {"Data.description", "Data.bid", "Data.ask"})
in
    #"Expanded Data"
```

Full credit to this excellent resource.

https://ssbi-blog.de/blog/technical-topics-english/the-environment-concept-in-m-for-power-query-and-power-bi-desktop-part-3/

Comment: I agree, this works. This was the reason I included `#sections[Section1]` as environment in my code (also tried `#shared`) but it didn't work. Your solution works by explicitly pulling the objects into the inner environment. But I was trying to create a dynamic solution, which means if I add another `shop_*` table, it would automatically be included. With your current solution, it still needs an update of the code. Do you think there's another way to do this? It's not a must-have to use `Expression.Evaluate()`. I just used that because I didn't see another way. If not, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: This should work, but it doesn't. Not sure why. `AddedTables = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Data", each Expression.Evaluate("shop_" & Text.From([shop]), #shared))`

Comment: I can't think of anything off the top of my head. Even if it were dynamic and you wanted to add another shop_, you would still have to change the code elsewhere so this would just be a complementary change to keep everything in sync. It might be worth posting a separate question on whether this is the best approach as I'm honestly not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to click these arrows to expand the tables. PowerBI doesn't understand this datatype; they only exist in Power Query and need to be expanded.

[image]

Comment: Added section [Edit 20 jun 2022] to clarify that expanding the table in the Data column is not the problem.

Comment: Any chance you can share your .pbix?

Comment: Why do you use Expression.Evaluate() out of interest? Have you seen the environment parameter complications noted here: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2015/02/06/expression-evaluate-in-power-querym/

Comment: Added [Edit 20 jun 2022 part 2] section with .pbix file

Comment: I'm aware of that blog post. I'm using `Expression.Evaluate()` to dynamically add the "shop_" string to the value in the column. So together, it forms the name of the table I need, and `Expression.Evaluate()` should then return said table.

Comment: OK, I get the same as you. Let me take a closer look and see if I can see the problem.

Comment: OK, I figured it out. I'll add a new answer with the code.