# Dynamic table referencing - environment and alternate methods

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

This is a follow-up to my question [Dynamic table data visible in query editor but blank in data view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72679896/dynamic-table-data-visible-in-query-editor-but-blank-in-data-view).

While using [Expression.Evaluate(document, environment)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/expression-evaluate) I was setting `environment`
either to `#sections[Section1]`

```
AddedTables = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Data", each Expression.Evaluate("shop_" & Text.From([shop]), #sections[Section1]))
```

or to `#shared`

```
AddedTables = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Data", each Expression.Evaluate("shop_" & Text.From([shop]), #shared))
```

but a working solution seems to be to explicitly define the inner and outer context objects in `environment`

```
AddedTables = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Data", each Expression.Evaluate("shop_" & Text.From([shop]), [shop_thehouse=shop_thehouse, shop_goldforex=shop_goldforex, shop_goldline=shop_goldline]))
```

So, my follow-up question here is 2-fold

1. Why does using `#shared` in the `environment` parameter not work?
   After all, `#shared` contains all objects, so also the ones that were explicitly defined by the working solution (`shop_thehouse`,`shop_goldforex`,`shop_goldline`).
2. Is there another or better way to dynamically reference an existing table/query, instead of using [Expression.Evaluate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/expression-evaluate) ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your answer might be explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-sections).

As I understand it, `#section` returns information from a *global* perspective, whereas `#shared` returns it from a *local* perspective. I *think*, maybe, in your usage context, there is nothing for the shop names to find locally (using `#shared`) since what you're looking for is in other tables. I *think* that yours is a global use case since you're looking for shop information from another table. Hopefully someone more familiar than I can confirm this.